# GIT staged all my pc files

Tags: git

I was working on Visual Studio code. I had GitHub installed on my PC, but then I removed it and created a GitHub folder on my own and selected that folder via the Visual Studio code git plugin.

Suddenly today it reported very large addition to the repository, so I allowed it to stage, but it removed all my PC files on desktop and also my cache and setting files.

Comment: Is your Desktop inside your Github folder? What does your directory structure look like? Are you tracking multiple repositories in Visual Studio? When you say "removed all my PC files" do you mean from git tracking or from the file? There's not really enough information here to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: @AnubhavTiwari Please give us more information so we can help you. What actions did you take?